# HA Proxy does not start up on Ubuntu 13

Tags: haproxy, ubuntu-13.04

I am trying to launch HA Proxy 1.4.24 on an ubuntu 13 VM via sudo.  My haproxy.cfg file is copied below.  However, when I use **sudo service haproxy start** or try **sudo /etc/init.d/haproxy** start, the process not start up.  Any ideas on troubleshooting this would be helpful.  The config file appears to pass the configuration test (**sudo haproxy -f haproxy.cfg -c** results in "**Configuration file is valid**").
Also, **Enabled** flag in the haproxy file in /etc/init.d is set to 1.
Port 80 does not appear to be bound by any other service.

**Update:**  I had set the enabled flag to 1 in the /etc/init.d/haproxy file as opposed to in the /etc/default/haproxy file - fixing this change allowed me to run haproxy normally.

```
global
    maxconn     25000 # Total Max Connections. This is dependent on ulimit
    daemon
    nbproc      4 # Number of processing cores. Dual Dual-core Opteron is 4 cores for example.

defaults
    mode        http
    clitimeout  60000
    srvtimeout  30000
    contimeout  4000
    timeout http-request 5s  # added to tackle slow http requests
        option abortonclose
        option forwardfor


listen  http_proxy *:80
        #bind *:80
    balance roundrobin # Load Balancing algorithm
    option httpchk
    option forwardfor # This sets X-Forwarded-For
        default_backend bk_web

# Dynamic part of the application
backend bk_web
    ## Define your servers to balance
    balance roundrobin ## change to URL hashing
    cookie MYSRV insert indirect nocache  ## check this NOTE TO SELF
    server server1 0.0.0.0:81 weight 1 maxconn 512 check
    server server2 0.0.0.0:82 weight 1 maxconn 512 check
```

Comment: Try running haproxy directly with `haproxy -f haproxy.cfg -db`

Comment: @Nathan C - the process runs fine when I use haproxy -f haproxy.cfg -db.  However, when I try sudo service haproxy start (or sudo /etc/init.d/haproxy start), the process does not launch.  Perhaps I should take a closer look at the haporxy file in /etc/init.d

Comment: pilot error - I set the enabled flag in the /etc/init.d instead of /etc/default.  Changing that fixed the issue - thank you Nathan and Kindule

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your should use

```
sh -x /etc/init.d/haproxy start
```

and this will print debug infomation.And where you got wrong.

Comment: I tried it earlier as well but did not pay enough attention to it - a closer look helped me realize the enabled flag was not setup in the correct place.  I fixed it - accepting your answer